# CDF of minimum of correlated and iid random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Consider two random variables 
$X_1=\min (W_1, W_2)$  and $ X_2=\min (W_3, W_4),$ where $W_1$, 
$W_2$,$W_3$ and $W_4$ are positive, identically distributed random variables. While $W_1$, $W_2$ are independent $W_3$, $W_4$ are correlated. We assume that the range of both $X_1$ and $X_2$ is from $0$ to $1$. Is it true that

$$\Pr \{X_2 \leq x \} \leq \Pr \{X_1 \leq x \},~~~ \forall x?$$

If yes, how to prove it? I would be grateful if any pointers to existing literature are given. Thanks!

Comment: "Correlated", like in *positively* correlated?

Comment: Yes we can assume as in positively correlated..

Comment: We "can"? It seems we must definitely assume that...

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(X_2> x\right)&{}={}&P\left(W_3> x,\ W_4> x\right)\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x,\ W_4> x\right\}}\right]\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}}{\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}\right]\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}\right]{}+{}\mathbb{C}ov\left({\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}},\ {\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}\right)\newline
&{}={}&P\left(W_1> x\right)P\left(W_2> x\right){}+{}\mathbb{C}ov\left({\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}},\ {\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}\right)\newline
&{}={}&P\left(X_1> x\right){}+{}\mathbb{C}ov\left({\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}},\ {\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4\ge x\right\}}\right)\newline
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Therefore,

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \mathbb{C}ov\left({\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}},\ {\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}\right){}\ge0&\iff& P\left(X_2> x\right)\ge P\left(X_1> x\right)\newline
> &&\newline
> &\iff& P\left(X_2\le x\right)\le P\left(X_1\le x\right)\,.
> \end{eqnarray*}
> $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer ki3i!. but, I cannot follow the proof from the second line. What does it mean the event $\textbf{1}_{A,B}?$

Comment: @Oliver, These are indicator functions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function. That is, ${\bf{1}}_{A}(\omega){}:={}\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1;&\,\,\,if\,\,\,\omega\in A\\0;&\,\,otherwise\end{array}\right.\,.$

Comment: @Oliver, A useful property of indicator functions is that $\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf{1}}_{A}\right]{}={}P\left(A\right)\,.$ This is also discussed at the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ki3i!! I am looking at your proof and the wiki link. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ ki3i, how come the line 3 to line 4? I agree that must be true, but, could not find out quickly; may be some axioms of indicator functions?

Comment: @Oliver, Its just the formula for the covariance between the two random variables, ${\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_3> x\right\}}$ and ${\bf{1}}_{\left\{W_4> x\right\}}$. The same formula for the covariance between any two random variables.

Comment: !. Thanks..I got it..The proof is understandable now..Thanks a lot..I am also thinking, what would happen if min is replaced by max.

Comment: ki3i.. you mentioned $Cov(a,b) \geq 0$, because I said so. In general $Cov(a,b)$ is a real value right?

Comment: Dear ki3i can we do this proof for 3 random variables? Little difficult with the co-variance part.

Comment: Dear ki3i if you have answer to my post here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121744/indicator-function-property  please let me know..